# How to read context from hyperlink on website

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web

I'm looking for method to read context from hyperlink on website. Is it possible?

For example:

```
website = "WEBSITE"
openwebsite = urllib2.urlopen(website)

hyperlink = _some_method_to_find_hyperlink(openwebsite)

get_context_from_hyper(hyperlink)
```

I was searching in Beautiful Shop, but I cannot find something usefull. 
I thinking that i could with lopp to find revelant hyperlink, and use urllib2 again, but website is quite large, and it would takes ages.

Comment: means you want of `href` attribute value from all `a` tags?

Answer (score 0):

You could go and try the [Beautiful Soup Package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/4.3.2) which enables you to parse HTML and thus extract any tag you might be looking for.